# Vue - bind a css class name with a property value

Tags: css, vuejs2

I would like to set a class to a child component based on in which parent component I am using it. So, for example, I have a dropdown menu, that I would like to use in more components, but I would like to give it a different class based on in which component I am using it.
Something like this, parent component top-bar:

```
<dropdown-menu :menu="link" :parent:'top-bar'></dropdown-menu>
```

And then in the dropdown-menu component:

```
<div class="dropdown" :class="{ parent: parent }">

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'dropdown-menu',
    props: ['parent'],
```

But, that is not working, how can I do this?

Comment: Not sure if this is the only problem but i believe `:parent:'top-bar'` should be `:parent='top-bar'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo `:parent:'top-bar'` -> `:parent='top-bar'` and your class binding would always pass the 'parent' string as a class. Learn more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

I also made a small working example:

```js
Vue.component('parent1', {
  template: '<div><dropdown-menu :menu="link" :parent="top_bar"></dropdown-menu></div>',
  data () {
      return {
          link: 'a link',
          top_bar: 'parent1'
      }
  }
});

Vue.component('parent2', {
  template: '<div><dropdown-menu :menu="link" :parent="top_bar"></dropdown-menu></div>',
  data () {
      return {
          link: 'another link',
          top_bar: 'parent2'
      }
  }
});

Vue.component('dropdown-menu', {
  template: '<div class="dropdown" v-bind:class="parent">{{ menu }}</div>',
  props: ['parent', 'menu']
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
.parent1 {
    color: red;
}

.parent2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent1></parent1>
  <parent2></parent2>
</div>
```